# How to pass an environment variable when change rooting?

Tags: shell, environment-variables, quoting, chroot

I don't seem to be able to pass an environment variable to a chroot:

```
$ sudo apt-get install debootstrap dchroot
$ sudo debootstrap trusty mychroot
$ sudo chroot mychroot /bin/bash -c "MY_VAR=5; echo ${MY_VAR}"

$
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use single quotes:

```
$ sudo chroot mychroot /bin/bash -c 'MY_VAR=5; echo ${MY_VAR}'
```

Answer (score 4):

Use yaegashi's answer, or escape the `$` like

```
$ sudo chroot mychroot /bin/bash -c "MY_VAR=5; echo \${MY_VAR}"
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$ XYZ=abc sudo -E chroot rootfs/ qemu-aarch64-static /bin/sh -c 'echo $XYZ' abc
```

Comment: Please consider [editing your post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/446821/edit) to include more context as to why you believe this to be an answer.

Answer (score 2):

for a login shell -c doesn't work. but /user/bin/env does :

```bsh
chroot /path/to/chroot/dir /usr/bin/env VAR_IN_CHROOT=$MYVAR /bin/bash --login
```

Answer (score 1):

I was looking for a way to pass an environment variable to the chroot calls from a debootstrap and noticed that the following also works:

```
$ sudo MY_VAR=5 chroot mychroot env | grep MY_VAR
MY_VAR=5
```

Comment: I like this solution, let me add that instead of MY_VAR=5 to the right of the sudo, if you used sudo -E that your chroot would inherit the user's environment. Seems sudo clears or purifies the environment. One other interesting usage: MY_VAR=${other_var} would allow you to selectively forward variables into the chroot.

Answer (score 1):

This really annoyed me for a while. I was trying to pass values that have spaces in them like

VALUE="123 345 567"
then I want to pass a variable like THING=$VALUE - this caused me endless attempts trying all the above a.nswers The only one that *might* have worked was Andy's answers but my user was not allow to pass the environment. So after a big sigh I decided to pass a file into my chroot, something like:

```bsh
echo THING=\"$VALUE\" > envvars
mv envars $CHROOT_DIR # What ever your chroot directory is
sudo chroot mychroot /bin/bash -c "source envars; echo \${THING}"
```

Since I am now just sourcing a file inside the chroot I can put what I want in there. This is good for complicated env-vars or for lots of them